# VBA - Select columns using numbers?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for an alternative to this `code`, but using numbers.
I want to select 5 columns, the start column is a variable, and then it selects 5 columns from this.

```
Columns("A:E").Select
```

How do I use `integers` instead, to reference columns? Something like below?

```
For n = 1 to 5
Columns("n : n + 4") .select
do sth
next n
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use resize like this:

```
For n = 1 To 5
    Columns(n).Resize(, 5).Select
    '~~> rest of your code
Next
```

In any *Range Manipulation* that you do, always keep at the back of your mind *Resize and Offset* property.

Comment: Hi, What if I want to get column range of just one particular column using column number

Comment: @JaydeepShil Can you elaborate more on what you want done?

Answer (score 14):

```
Columns("A:E").Select
```

Can be directly replaced by

```
Columns(1).Resize(, 5).EntireColumn.Select
```

Where 1 can be replaced by a variable

```
n = 5
Columns(n).Resize(, n+4).EntireColumn.Select
```

In my opinion you are best dealing with a block of columns rather than looping through columns n to n + 4 as it is more efficient.

In addition, using select will slow your code down. So instead of selecting your columns and then performing an action on the selection try instead to perform the action directly. Below is an example to change the colour of columns A-E to yellow.

```
Columns(1).Resize(, 5).EntireColumn.Interior.Color = 65535
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `range` with `cells` to get the effect you want (but it would be better not to use select if you don't have to)

```
For n = 1 to 5
range(cells(1,n).entirecolumn,cells(1,n+4).entirecolumn).Select
do sth
next n
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following, where `n` is your variable and x is your offset (4 in this case):

```
LEFT(ADDRESS(1,n+x,4),1)
```

This will return the letter of that column (so for n=1 and x=4, it'll return A+4 = E). You can then use `INDIRECT()` to reference this, as so:

```
COLUMNS(INDIRECT(LEFT(ADDRESS(1,n,4),1)&":"&LEFT(ADDRESS(1,n+x,4),1)))
```

which with n=1, x=4 becomes:

```
COLUMNS(INDIRECT("A"&":"&"E"))
```

and so:

```
COLUMNS(A:E)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example code below I use variables just to show how the command could be used for other situations.

```
FirstCol = 1
LastCol = FirstCol + 5
Range(Columns(FirstCol), Columns(LastCol)).Select
```

Answer (score 1):

no need for loops or such.. try this..

```
dim startColumnas integer

dim endColumn as integer

startColumn = 7

endColumn = 24

Range(Cells(, startColumn), Cells(, endColumn)).ColumnWidth = 3.8 ' <~~ whatever width you want to set..*
```

Comment: This seems to only select the first row in those columns for me.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because using Range and Cells seemed to be the easiest to read. Use `.EntireColumn` to get more than just cells, like this:   `Range(Cells(, startColumn), Cells(, endColumn)).EntireColumn.Select`

Comment: An even easier to read version is  `Range(Columns(startColumn), Columns(endColumn)).Select`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify addresses as "R1C2" instead of "B2". Under **File -> Options -> Formuals -> Workingg with Formulas** there is a toggle **R1C1 reference style**. which can be set, as illustrated below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar thing.
My problem was to find the last column based on row 5 and then select 3 columns before including the last column.

```
Dim lColumn As Long

lColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(5,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
MsgBox ("The last used column is: " & lColumn)
Range(Columns(lColumn - 3), Columns(lColumn)).Select
```

Message box is optional as it is more of a control check. If you want to select the columns after the last column then you simply reverse the range selection

```
Dim lColumn As Long

lColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(5,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
MsgBox ("The last used column is: " & lColumn)
Range(Columns(lColumn), Columns(lColumn + 3)).Select
```

Answer (score -1):

In this way, you can start to select data even behind column "Z" and select a lot of columns.

```
Sub SelectColumNums()
    Dim xCol1 As Integer, xNumOfCols as integer
    xCol1 = 26
    xNumOfCols = 17
    Range(Columns(xCol1), Columns(xCol1 + xNumOfCols)).Select
End Sub
```