# Copy Partial Array in Excel and Transpose

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, copy, excel-2010

In a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413840/copy-partial-row-identified-by-id) I was copying a row from an 'Active' spreadsheet and putting it on a 'Term' spreadsheet however we've changed how the columns are on the 'Active' sheet.

Previously I would copy columns 'A:G' on the Active sheet and paste in in 'A:G' on the 'Term'.

Now what was 'A:G' is 'A:D' and then 'G:I' so I am trying to figure out how to copy each section of the row based on column numbers.

The entire existing code is here:

```
Option Explicit

Const Err_EmpNotFound = 1000

Public Function NextRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal col As Variant = 1) As Long
    With ws
        NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
End Function

Sub TEST_COPY()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim wsActive As Worksheet, wsTerm As Worksheet
    Dim wbCOPYMaster As Workbook

    Set wbCOPYMaster = Workbooks("COPY.xlsx")
    Set wsActive = wbCOPYMaster.Worksheets("Active Employees")
    Set wsTerm = wbCOPYMaster.Worksheets("Terminations")

    wsActive.Activate

    'Locate the employee
    Dim rngEmployee As Range, sEmployeeID As String
    Dim empDataArr As Variant, empDataArr2 As Variant
    sEmployeeID = Application.InputBox("Enter Employee ID")
    Set rngEmployee = wsActive.Range("B:B").Find(sEmployeeID, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If rngEmployee Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + Err_EmpNotFound, Description:="Employee Not Found"
    End If

    'Prompt before termination (assume's employee's name is column 6 (col F)
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to terminate " & wsActive.Cells(rngEmployee.Row, _
            6) & "?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

        empDataArr = wsActive.Range("A" & rngEmployee.Row & ":BH" & rngEmployee.Row)
        empDataArr2 = wsActive.Range("CY" & rngEmployee.Row & ":DN" & rngEmployee.Row)

    'Add employee to termination sheet
    With wsTerm.Rows(NextRow(wsTerm))
        .Columns("A:BH") = empDataArr
        .Columns("BI:BX") = empDataArr2
        .Columns("BY") = Date
    End With

    'Delete the data
    rngEmployee.EntireRow.Delete

    'Notify user of completion
    MsgBox "Employee was successfully terminated!"
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Dim errBox As Long
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case Err_EmpNotFound + vbObjectError
            errBox = MsgBox(Err.Description, vbRetryCancel)
            If errBox = vbRetry Then
                Err.Clear
                TEST_COPY
                End
            End If
        Case Else
            MsgBox Err.Description, Title:=Err.Number
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42155827/2727437) shows an alternative to selecting multiple columns

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I understand how I can select columns to paste in by using "Columns(1).Resize(, 5).EntireColumn.Select" in place of ".Columns("A:G") "



`With wsTerm.Rows(NextRow(wsTerm))
        .Columns("A:G") = empDataArr
        .Columns("H") = Date
    End With`


The issue is the ".Columns("A:G")" within the code here is the range that is being filled in on the term sheet while the empDataArr is the datafrom the active tab being pasted. 

I need to have a portion 'A:D' and then 'G:I' from the active tab which is a selection of the empDataArr array. I can't figure out how to

Comment: the lazy way to make this work with little changes would be convert `Sub EmployeeTermination()` to `Function EmployeeTermination(byval colStart as long, byval colEnd as long)` and also change `.Columns("A:G")` to `Columns(colStart).Resize(, colEnd-colStart+1).EntireColumn`. Then you'd create a different `Sub` to call `EmployeeTermination 2, 6`, etc as needed.

Comment: otherwise you have to re-work the way that you select your data for your array, copy it, and delete it

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 there wouldn't be a way to edit `empDataArr = rngEmployee.EntireRow.Cells` to only include columns A:D of the rngEmployee row and then have a second array for G:I?

Comment: oof, yeah, that's a pretty simple solution as well!

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I edited `empDataArr = rngEmployee.Columns("A:BH").Cells` and it fills into `.Columns("A:BH") = empDataArr` but for some reason the cells are shifted left one column

Comment: So it is somehow setting the array to be B:BH and filling into A:BH on the term tab.

Comment: that's curious... i'm not sure why it would do that

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 the only thing I can think is that `Set rngEmployee` starts in column 'B' and since 'A' is to the left of that, it is failing. 

Sorta like how vlookup can't look left. 

I even tried setting a separate array for just column 'A' and it still didn't work corrrectly.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2

I'm not sure though but here is the full code I have at this point. (up in the top post)

Comment: yeah i think you're exactly right on why it wont let you include column A. Instead of adding data to the arrays based on the employee range you could instead use the employee range as a reference to get the correct row number `empDataArr = wsActive.Range("A" & rngEmployee.row & ":BH" & rngEmployee.row)`

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 so that works for the first array, empDataArr but I can't get your suggestion to work for empDataArr2 `empDataArr2 = rngEmployee.Columns("CY:DN").Cells` I tried editing the ":BH" section and just changing the array being set there but it didn't work. I also tried adding   `& "CY:DN" ` within your edit and that didn't work either.

Comment: should just be `empDataArr2 = wsActive.Range("CY" & rngEmployee.row & ":DN" & rngEmployee.row)`

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 thank you so much. That works perfectly.

Comment: code updated to be finalized.